# Show that $\text{span}(S_{1}\cup S_{2}) = \text{span}(S_{1}) + \text{span}(S_{2})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are arbitrary subsets of a vector space $V$, then $\text{span}(S_{1}\cup S_{2}) = \text{span}(S_{1}) + \text{span}(S_{2})$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

In both cases, we are going to assume that $S_{1} = \{s_{11},s_{12},\ldots\}$ and $S_{2} = \{s_{21},s_{22},\ldots\}$.

Let us prove the inclusion $\subseteq$ first.

If $v\in\text{span}(S_{1}\cup S_{2})$, then we have that

\begin{align*}
v = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}s_{1i} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}s_{2j} = v_{1} + v_{2}
\end{align*}
where $v_{1}\in\text{span}(S_{1})$ and $v_{2}\in\text{span}(S_{2})$, and we are done.

Conversely, let us prove the converse inclusion $\supseteq$.

Consequently, we have that $v = v_{1} + v_{2}$, where $v_{1}\in\text{span}(S_{1})$ and $v_{2}\in\text{span}(S_{2})$, that is to say,
\begin{align*}
v = v_{1} + v_{2} & = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}s_{1i} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}s_{2j}\\\\
& = \left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}s_{1i} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}0s_{2j}\right] + \left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}0s_{1i} +\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}s_{2j}\right]
\end{align*}

Thus $v_{k}\in\text{span}(S_{1}\cup S_{2})$, which means that $v\in\text{span}(S_{1}\cup S_{2})$ just as desired.

Could someone verify if I am reasoning correctly?

Comment: Hi! An element $v\in \text{span}(S)$ is a _**finite**_ linear combination of element of $S$. Apart from this, your proof is correct

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I haved edited it. Am I on the right track?

Comment: $S_1$ and $S_2$ can be infinite, but an element in $\text{span}(S_1)$ is a finite sum (by definition). The last equality passage is also unnecessary; you can conclude without write it. And finally there is a typo mistake in the last line of the proof ($v_k$). But in general the proof is good!